# Spark file streaming does not work properly with simultaneously added files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using **spark.readStream** to process some csv files in a folder. When I added multiple files to that folder simultaneously, only some of them are processed while the rest of the files remain in the folder without any progress.For example, I add 5 files but only 2 of them are processed.

I can solve this problem using **maxFilesPerTrigger** option and setting a **trigger interval** i.e. *.trigger(ProcessingTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))*.

However, I do not understand why Spark does not work properly in this scenario. What is the cause of this problem and is there a better solution ?

I'm using Spark 3.4.1 with Scala 2.13

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the modification dates of files. They were simply ignored because of the maxFileAgeMs parameter.